# Scope of an object created in an if-condition in C++

Tags: c++

In the following example

```
void fun() {
    if(int i=SOME_VALUE) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What is the scope of i? Can we use it inside the if-block? Can we use it inside the else-block?

*Edit:*

As a follow-up, in this modified example

```
void fun() {
    if(int i=SOME_VALUE) {
        // ...
    } else if(int j=SOME_OTHER_VALUE){
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Can we access both i and j in the else clause?

Comment: Why not just try it and you will find out?

Comment: It's the scope of both, but it's almost always cleaner _not_ to declare anything in a condition.  It makes reading and understanding the program significantly harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and yes.

A typical use for this is dynamic casting:

```
if (auto p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base_pointer))
{
    // p is a Derived*
}
else
{
    // not the right dynamic type
}
```

Another construction I've been finding useful:

```
if (auto fp = std::unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)>(std::fopen("file.txt", "rb"), std::fclose))
{
    // file exists, use fp.get()
}
else
{
    // file does not exist
}
```

And one more:

```
if (pid_t pid = fork())
{
    waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0);
}
else
{
    execl("/bin/rm", "/bin/rm", "-rf", "/", static_cast<char*>(nullptr));
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but the last example is potentially dangerous. Maybe warn it's intended for humor and not use in real code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the variable declared in the `if` condition in the `else` substatement like your example.

However, if you declare `i` inside the `if` substatement like this:

```
if (some_condition) {
    int i = 42;
    // ...
} else {
    std::cout << i;  //error
    // ...
}
```

in the `else` part, the variable `i` is no longer in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the variable is "created" in the outermost scope and only then, evaluated in the `if` condition. Your code could be rewritten like:

```
int i = SOME_VALUE;
if(i) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

and not like:

```
if(SOME_VALUE) {
    int i = SOME_VALUE;
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

as you may have though.

The second question can be answered the same way.